# Windows Form Application & Web Application Form

Tags: c#

I have one Windows Form Application project and Web Application Form project. Can I use the Windows Form Application to call one of them aspx from Web Application Form?

Thank & Regard

Comment: Are you looking for a way to display the web page inside your Win form application? If so have a look at the WebBrowser control.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use `HttpClient` class. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) you can read more. By the way:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var result = await client.GetAsync("your url");
```

You can also do `POST` calls instead of `GET` calls.

Comment: Sorry, I have pasted your code in my windows form but it say HttpClient namespace could not be found.

Comment: Probably you need to add to your project `System.Net.Http` reference.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use HTTPClient to call aspx page from your windows form application. Here is the example of HTTP Client http://www.dotnetperls.com/httpclient